# Tornado celery can't use gen.Task or CallBack

Tags: python, json, redis, celery, tornado

```
class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        tasks.sleep.apply_async(args=[5], callback=self.on_result)

    def on_result(self, response):
        self.write(str(response.result))
        self.finish()
```

raise error :

```
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <bound method AsyncHandler.on_result 
of <__main__.AsyncHandler object at 0x10e7a19d0>> is not JSON serializable
```

The broker and backends all use redis, I just copied from 
https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery

When I use amqp broker and redis backends it works well, but not when using the redis broker. Is this because tornado async does not support redis broker?

Comment: when i  use amqp  broker and redis backends  it works well,   Because  tornado async  does not support redis borker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery) says:

> NOTE: Currently callbacks only work with AMQP and Redis backends. To use the Redis backend, you must install tornado-redis.

So tornado-celery does not support redis as a broker... it works when I use rabbitmq as a broker + redis as a backend.